# Fastest way to repeatedly iterate over the same subsets of a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array and a list of indices that I want to iterate over many times.

The following code does what I want, but it seems very inefficient:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random(10)
indices = [8, 4, 2]

for _ in range(10):
    
    # Some changes to a
    sa = np.array([a[i] for i in indices])
    # Some actions that use sa
```

Is there a better way to define `sa`? And is there a way that I don't have to redefine `sa` at every iteration, but instead have it point directly to the selected indices of `a`?

Comment: `sa = np.intersect1d(a,indices)`?

Comment: Thanks! That works in the above example, but does not select based on the indices. I changed the example so that `a` does not have the same values as its index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General note - if you have anything that can be effectively run in the `for` loop, without complex calculations in a single iteration - probably it can be vectorized in `numpy`.

Having this said, what you are looking for:

```py
a[indices]
```

Comment: Thanks! But this would still require to generate a new array at every iteration, right?

Comment: No, you just replace your iteration with `sa = a[indices]`